# Why in java socket, we can't send message continuously?

Tags: java, sockets

This is my rough program. I have two clients one server I want to get the result
Test1
Test2
...
...
but it only give me Test1...

I tried to add a reply method in server and a receive method. Just like I note below, the problem solved. The result is like 
Test1
Test1
Test2
Test2
Test1
Test2

Why I must add this reply method?

### Server:

```
ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
while ( keys.hasNext() ) {
    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)keys.next();
    keys.remove();

    if (!key.isValid()) 
        continue;

    if (key.isReadable()) {
        SocketChannel nsc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                     // clear buffer for reading
        readBuffer.clear();
        int nBytes = nsc.read(readBuffer);
        DataInputStream ist = new DataInputStream (
                              new ByteArrayInputStream(readBuffer.array()));
        String info = ist.readUTF();
        switch (info) {
            case TAKE:
                System.out.println("Test1");
                /*writeBuffer.clear();
                  writeBuffer.putInt(1);
                  writeBuffer.flip();
                  nsc.write(writeBuffer);*/ // the reply method
                break;
            case BUN:
                System.out.println("Test2");
                  break;
          }
      }
  }
```

### Client:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

do {
    try {
        out.writeUTF("TAKE ");
        //in.readInt(); the receive method
        out.writeUTF("BUN ");

        Thread.sleep(id + 1);
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
         sock.close();
         throw ioe;
     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
 } while (true);
```

Comment: seems I forgot to put something. I will add right now

Answer (score 0):

Using `ByteBuffer.array()` isn't valid: you have to `flip()` the buffer and `get()` from it, rather than just ignoring its position and limit as you are now. Or construct the `ByteArrayOutputStream` using `position()` and `limit()` as the offset and length arguments.

Comment: OK but you're still misusing the ByteBuffer.